# Forwarding to std::async

Tags: c++, c++11

This is my (simplified) code where I'm trying to call async forwarding arguments:

```
template<typename Ret, typename ... Args>
class CallbackAsyncTask {
public:
    CallbackAsyncTask() {
    }
    virtual ~CallbackAsyncTask() = default;

    void execute( Args&& ... args ) {
        execute(&CallbackAsyncTask<Ret, Args...>::onBackground, this, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
protected:
    virtual Ret onBackground( Args& ... args ) = 0;
    template<typename Fn, typename ... Argss>
    void execute( Fn&& fn, Argss&& ... args ) noexcept(false) {
        std::async(std::launch::async, std::forward<Fn>(fn), std::forward<Argss>(args)...);
    }
};

class Child: public CallbackAsyncTask<int, int> {
public:
    virtual int onBackground( int& i ) {
        return i;
    }
};

int main() {
    Child c;
    c.execute(15);
    return 0;
}
```

I get this error:

```
../main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void CallbackAsyncTask<Ret, Args>::execute(Fn&&, Argss&& ...) [with Fn = int (CallbackAsyncTask<int, int>::*)(int&); Argss = {CallbackAsyncTask<int, int>* const, int}; Ret = int; Args = {int}]’:
../main.cpp:27:98:   required from ‘void CallbackAsyncTask<Ret, Args>::execute(Args&& ...) [with Ret = int; Args = {int}]’
../main.cpp:46:17:   required from here
../main.cpp:33:90: error: no matching function for call to ‘async(std::launch, int (CallbackAsyncTask<int, int>::*)(int&), CallbackAsyncTask<int, int>* const, int)’
         std::async(std::launch::async, std::forward<Fn>(fn), std::forward<Argss>(args)...);
                                                                                          ^
../main.cpp:33:90: note: candidates are:
In file included from ../main.cpp:13:0:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/future:1532:5: note: template<class _Fn, class ... _Args> std::future<typename std::result_of<_Functor(_ArgTypes ...)>::type> std::async(std::launch, _Fn&&, _Args&& ...)
     async(launch __policy, _Fn&& __fn, _Args&&... __args)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/future:1532:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/future: In substitution of ‘template<class _Fn, class ... _Args> std::future<typename std::result_of<_Functor(_ArgTypes ...)>::type> std::async(std::launch, _Fn&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Fn = int (CallbackAsyncTask<int, int>::*)(int&); _Args = {CallbackAsyncTask<int, int>* const, int}]’:
../main.cpp:33:90:   required from ‘void CallbackAsyncTask<Ret, Args>::execute(Fn&&, Argss&& ...) [with Fn = int (CallbackAsyncTask<int, int>::*)(int&); Argss = {CallbackAsyncTask<int, int>* const, int}; Ret = int; Args = {int}]’
../main.cpp:27:98:   required from ‘void CallbackAsyncTask<Ret, Args>::execute(Args&& ...) [with Ret = int; Args = {int}]’
../main.cpp:46:17:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/future:1532:5: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<int (CallbackAsyncTask<int, int>::*(CallbackAsyncTask<int, int>*, int))(int&)>’
../main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void CallbackAsyncTask<Ret, Args>::execute(Fn&&, Argss&& ...) [with Fn = int (CallbackAsyncTask<int, int>::*)(int&); Argss = {CallbackAsyncTask<int, int>* const, int}; Ret = int; Args = {int}]’:
../main.cpp:27:98:   required from ‘void CallbackAsyncTask<Ret, Args>::execute(Args&& ...) [with Ret = int; Args = {int}]’
../main.cpp:46:17:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/future:1552:5: note: template<class _Fn, class ... _Args> std::future<typename std::result_of<_Functor(_ArgTypes ...)>::type> std::async(_Fn&&, _Args&& ...)
     async(_Fn&& __fn, _Args&&... __args)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/future:1552:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/future: In substitution of ‘template<class _Fn, class ... _Args> std::future<typename std::result_of<_Functor(_ArgTypes ...)>::type> std::async(_Fn&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Fn = std::launch; _Args = {int (CallbackAsyncTask<int, int>::*)(int&), CallbackAsyncTask<int, int>* const, int}]’:
../main.cpp:33:90:   required from ‘void CallbackAsyncTask<Ret, Args>::execute(Fn&&, Argss&& ...) [with Fn = int (CallbackAsyncTask<int, int>::*)(int&); Argss = {CallbackAsyncTask<int, int>* const, int}; Ret = int; Args = {int}]’
../main.cpp:27:98:   required from ‘void CallbackAsyncTask<Ret, Args>::execute(Args&& ...) [with Ret = int; Args = {int}]’
../main.cpp:46:17:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/future:1552:5: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<std::launch(int (CallbackAsyncTask<int, int>::*)(int&), CallbackAsyncTask<int, int>*, int)>’
```

What I am missing? Compiler Gcc 4.8.3

Comment: Code snippet you shared looks fine. It compiles and runs. Tried on MSVC, gcc 8.3. Please share caller code as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause is these two lines

```
virtual Ret onBackground( Args& ... args ) = 0;

virtual int onBackground( int& i )
```

When launching the task, the arguments are converted either directly or as if by the `std::thread` constructor. [That one does `decay_copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread) on the arguments when invoking the callable, so a non-const lvalue reference cannot bind to the argument.

Change the way `onBackground` accepts arguments. For instance, a const lvalue refernce works. [See live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6761a4cdfca028b3).

Comment: Thank you for your response. What I didn't understand: ok, I can use a const reference, would it change anything using decay_copy as class thread does? Or not?

Comment: @greywolf82 - Not sure I understand the question. The `decay_copy` happens on the library side. We have no control over it.

Comment: Ok, I got it, you are saying decay_copy is on std::async or at least in glibc, so my only alternative is to use a const reference. Thanks!